# azure notification hub SendNotificationAsync response

Tags: azure, push-notification, azure-notificationhub

We're currently using Azure Notification HUB to send push notifications both to iOS and Android phones. The SendNotificationAsync method returns a Task, and using its Result properties we are trying to iterate through the results. My question is whether we can extract the result somehow when an error occurs (for eg invalid registration id is sent to azure) in a proper way (currently we are parsing the outcome and string matching the error message, which is not the appropriate solution).